# Google map app crashes on android OS 4.3

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I built an app for map. Added all the necessary permissions and generated the api key but it is still crashing. I am working on command line and implemented it on Android 4.3 OS.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

Manifest File

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission                  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
      Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <permission
  android:name="mapdemo.exp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="mapdemo.exp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAS08XqNbdRuxsOwNrosza0WE2mijfdoO8"/>
 <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="4323000" />

</application>
```

Tried this

```
   public class ActivityMain extends Activity
   {
   public GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try
      {
        Log.e("loading map. . . .", "loading map. . . ");
        initilizeMap();
      }  
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("catch. . .", "catch. . .");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

private void initilizeMap()
  {
    Log.e("initializing map. . . ", "initializing map. . ");
    if (googleMap == null)
      {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();            
        if (googleMap == null)
         {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      }
  }

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
}
```

Comment: Post your java code too

Comment: I followed the link  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2. I've posted the java code also

Comment: you running it on device or emulator ?

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: testing on os installed on pc not using eclipse..

Comment: @user3357003 :- Did you add google play services lib in your project ?

Comment: @user3243147 yes everything added i have provide proper certificate key, api key, google play services lib but still not able to debug

Comment: can you post your logcat ?

Comment: @user3243147 i developing app in command line and testing on os installed on pc..ne-debugger app is not working so not able to get logcat..

Comment: Did you add MapFragment/SupportMapFragment in your activity?

Comment: @VipulShah Not on IDE I building app from command line using apache ant..

Comment: @user3243147 no how to add that refer me some links if u have..

Comment: MainActivity is your full code?

Comment: @user3243147 yeah and i have refered this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

In xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
         />

    </LinearLayout>
```

In Activity:-

```
    public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
        // Google Map
        public GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            Log.e("loading map. . . .", "loading map. . . ");
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("catch. . .", "catch. . .");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
         * MapFunctionality mf = new MapFunctionality(); mf.currentLoc();
         * mf.addMarker();
         */
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        // MapFunctionality mf = new MapFunctionality();
        Log.e("initializing map. . . ", "initializing map. . ");
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            // mf.currentLoc();
            // mf.addMarker();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

Follow these [Link 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) and [Link 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)
Hope it will help you to sort out with your problem 
Good Luck

Comment: where are you running your code in emulator or in device?

Comment: I followed as you mentioned and I m not running app on emulator.

Comment: I already tried those examples and others too but it still keeps crashing. i'll post the code i tried check it out...

Comment: if there is not logcat error,
how can we ol help you out?

Comment: I'm bout the error.
The code is same which i'd written
Which errors you are having?

Comment: i'll try it in eclipse and message u.. Thanks for ur support